# Como seleccionar un objeto en concreto en una arraylist abstracta

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, consola, clase-abstracta

¡Hola!

Estoy bastante estancada en un método en el que pretendo recorrer un arraylist de tipo abstracto que en este caso es Persona. Dentro de ese arraylist de Personas lo que he hecho ha sido añadir dos objetos: Usuarios y Bibliotecarios gracias a un método llamado solicitarDatosPersona que debe estar sobreescrito tanto en la clase Usuario como en Bibliotecario. El objetivo del método es buscar el NIF y contraseña del bibliotecario y el teléfono móvil y email del usuario para dar acceso al Bibliotecario o al usuario a otro menú que todavía no he creado.

Por ahora lo que he hecho ha sido solo comprobar que al introducir una contraseña para el bibliotecario sea igual que a la del Arraylist Persona. Pero no me detecta la contraseña que he introducido, el método se llama accesoPassword() y está en Bibliotecario.

Este sería el código de la clase Persona:

```
public abstract class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido1;
    private String apellido2;
    private Integer edad;

public Persona(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, Integer edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

//He creado los respectivos setters y getters pero no lo pondré porque sino sería un tanto largo

 public Persona solicitarDatosPersona() {
        Persona persona = null;
        return persona;
    }
/*
Este método era una prueba para comprobar si funcionaba correctamente solicitarDatosPersona pero daba error y por tanto utilizo el de arriba.
    public void solicitarDatosPersona() {
        Persona usuario= new Usuario();
        Persona bibliotecario = new Bibliotecario();
        List<Persona> personaList= new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre");
        Scanner nombre1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre = nombre1.nextLine();
        usuario.setNombre(nombre);
        bibliotecario.setNombre(nombre);
    }

 */
```

Por otro lado tengo la clase Bibliotecario:

```
public class Bibliotecario extends Persona {
    private String puestoTrabajo;
    private String nif;
    private String password;

    public Bibliotecario() {

    }

    public Bibliotecario(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, Integer edad, String puestoTrabajo, String nif, String password) {
        super(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad);
        this.puestoTrabajo = puestoTrabajo;
        this.nif = nif;
        this.password = password;
    }

 @Override
    public Bibliotecario solicitarDatosPersona() {
        Biblioteca biblioteca= new Biblioteca();
        Bibliotecario bibliotecario= new Bibliotecario();
        ArrayList<Bibliotecario> bibliotecarioList= new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre");
        Scanner nombre2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre = nombre2.nextLine();
        bibliotecario.setNombre(nombre);

        System.out.println("Introduce el Primer Apellido:");
        Scanner apellido1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String primerApellido = apellido1.nextLine();
        bibliotecario.setApellido1(primerApellido);

        System.out.println("Introduce el Segundo Apellido:");
        Scanner apellido2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String segundoApellido = apellido2.nextLine();
        bibliotecario.setApellido2(segundoApellido);

        System.out.println("Introduce la edad:");
        Scanner edad1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer edad = Integer.parseInt(edad1.nextLine());
        bibliotecario.setEdad(edad);

        System.out.println("Introduce el puesto de trabajo:");
        Scanner pusT = new Scanner(System.in);
        String puestoTrabajo = pusT.nextLine();
        bibliotecario.setPuestoTrabajo(puestoTrabajo);

        System.out.println("Introduce el NIF:");
        Scanner nif1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nif = nif1.nextLine();
        bibliotecario.setNif(nif);

        System.out.println("Introduce el Password:");
        Scanner password1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = password1.nextLine();
        bibliotecario.setPassword(password);

        bibliotecarioList.add(bibliotecario);
      //  biblioteca.getPersonaList().add(bibliotecario);
        Biblioteca.setBibliotecarioList(bibliotecarioList);
        return bibliotecario;
    }

 public static void accesoPassword() {

        System.out.print("\n Introduce tu contraseña: ");
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String contrasena = leer.nextLine();
        int comprobante = 1;
        //ArrayList<Bibliotecario> bibliotecarios = new ArrayList<>();
       // Bibliotecario bibliotecario =new Bibliotecario();

     //biblioteca.getPersonaList().get(i).equals(bibliotecario.getPassword())
        for (int i = 0; i < Biblioteca.getBibliotecarioList().size(); i++) {
            if (Biblioteca.getBibliotecarioList().equals(contrasena)) {
                System.out.println("\n" +"Acceso correcto");
                comprobante = 0;
            }
        }
        if (comprobante == 1) {
            System.out.println("No es correcto");
        }

    }
```

Y la clase Usuario:

```
public class Usuario extends Persona {
    private Integer telefono;
    private String direccion;
    private Integer codigoPostal;
    private String correoElectronico;
    private List<Reserva> listaReserva;

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public Usuario(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, Integer edad, Integer telefono, String direccion, Integer codigoPostal, String correoElectronico, List<Reserva> listaReserva) {
        super(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad);
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
        this.correoElectronico = correoElectronico;
        this.listaReserva = listaReserva;
    }

//omito los setters y getters pero que conste que los tengo

@Override
    public Usuario solicitarDatosPersona() {

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        List<Persona> usuarioList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Introduce el Nombre:");
        Scanner nombre1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre = nombre1.nextLine();
        usuario.setNombre(nombre);

        System.out.println("Introduce el Primer Apellido:");
        Scanner apellido1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String primerApellido = apellido1.nextLine();
        usuario.setApellido1(primerApellido);

        System.out.println("Introduce el Segundo Apellido:");
        Scanner apellido2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String segundoApellido = apellido2.nextLine();
        usuario.setApellido2(segundoApellido);

        System.out.println("Introduce la edad:");
        Scanner edad1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer edad = Integer.parseInt(edad1.nextLine());
        usuario.setEdad(edad);

        System.out.println("Introduce el teléfono:");
        Scanner tel = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer telefono = Integer.parseInt(tel.nextLine());
        usuario.setTelefono(telefono);

        System.out.println("Introduce la dirección:");
        Scanner direc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String direccion = direc.nextLine();
        usuario.setDireccion(direccion);

        System.out.println("Introduce el código postal:");
        Scanner cp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer codigoPostal = Integer.parseInt(cp.nextLine());
        usuario.setCodigoPostal(codigoPostal);

        System.out.println("Introduce el correo electrónico");
        Scanner email = new Scanner(System.in);
        String correo = email.nextLine();
        usuario.setCorreoElectronico(correo);
        //usuario.setListaReserva(null);

        usuarioList.add(usuario);
        return usuario;
    }
}
```

Luego en un amago de intento de hacer o solucionar algo tengo la clase Biblioteca que le añadido las siguientes listas:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    private String nombreBiblioteca;
    private static List<Libro> libroList;
    private static List<Persona> personaList;
    private static List<Bibliotecario> bibliotecarioList;
    private static List<Usuario> usuarioList;
}
```

Y por último tenemos el Main que es de está manera:

```
public int executeMainMenu() {
        int entrada;
        Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de la accion que quieres relizar");

            System.out.println(" 1. Comprobar que solicitarDatosPersona es correcto");
            System.out.println(" 2. Iniciar sesion como bibliotecario");
            System.out.print("\n Para salir pulse 9 ");
            System.out.print("\n Elija una opción (1-2): ");

            entrada = opcion.nextInt();
        } while (entrada > 10 || entrada < 1);


        return entrada;
    }

    //todo ordenarlo más tarde
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int entrada;
        Menu Menu = new Menu();

        entrada = Menu.executeMainMenu();
        Biblioteca biblioteca= new Biblioteca();
        Persona bibliotecario = new Bibliotecario();
        Persona usuario = new Usuario();
        Date date= new Date();
        Libro libro1=new Libro("001a", "El quijote", "Cervantes", "el quijote pum", 5, 5);
        ArrayList<Libro> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Persona> personaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Reserva> reservaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        myList.add(libro1);
        myList.add(new Libro("002a", "El principito", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "Editoriales Ignatius", 5, 5));
        myList.add(new Libro("003a", "50 Sombras de Grey", "Sam Taylor-Wood", "Editoriales Maitus", 5, 5));
        myList.add(new Libro("004a", "La casa de Bernarda Alba", "Lorca", "Lorca Editorial", 5, 0));
        myList.add(new Libro("005a", "100 años de soledad", "Garcia Marquez", "Editorial Garcia", 5, 5));

        /*
        personaArrayList.add(new Bibliotecario("Ignacio", "Akrich", "Vazquez", 25, "Vicedirector", "43152327A", "12345678"));
        personaArrayList.add(new Bibliotecario("Maite", "Ladaria", "Sanchez", 25, "Directora", "43152327E", "12345678"));
*/
        /**
         *TODO A TENER EN CUENTA QUE USUARIO TIENE UN ARRAYLIST
         * reservaArrayList.add(new Reserva(libro1, date));
         */
/*
        personaArrayList.add(new Usuario("Paco", "Martinez", "Pedro", 55, 658490268, "Calle 13", 07003, "pacomartinez@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));
        personaArrayList.add(new Usuario("Pamela", "Mejia", "Fontseca", 20, 658490268, "Calle Blanquerna", 07777, "pamelamejia@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));

*/

        while (entrada != 20) {
            switch (entrada) {
              
                case 1:

                    personaArrayList.add(bibliotecario.solicitarDatosPersona());
                    System.out.println(personaArrayList);
                    entrada = Menu.executeMainMenu();
                case 2:
                    Bibliotecario.accesoPassword();
                    entrada = Menu.executeMainMenu();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("hasta lueguito");

            }
        }

    }


}
```

He acortado el Main para que sea más corto. No sé si hay alguna solución a como puedo realizar el método de accesoPassword de Bibliotecario y como podría recorrer la lista y escoger la contraseña introducida. Es importante que en el ejercicio que nos mandan nos pone lo siguiente del metodo solicitarDatosPersona:

Crea un método llamado solicitarDatosPersona de la clase Persona, que pide los datos y los va actualizando en la propia instancia que utiliza este método. Este método será sobreescrito por las clases hijas, de manera que además de hacer lo que hace el método de la clase padre, incluirá la solicitud de datos de las clases hijas.
f.  Incluye en el menú, para que el bibliotecario, pueda dar de alta más bibliotecarios (compañeros de trabajo), y usuarios, de manera que utilizará el método anterior. Aclaración: tendremos un arraylist de persona, lo que ocurre es que nunca almacenaremos personas, sino Usuarios o Bibliotecarios, por tanto, se entiende que la clase Persona será una clase abstracta. En consecuencia, el menú de gestión del bibliotecario llamará a solicitarDatosPersona para un usuario o para un bibliotecario, y cuando hayamos completado esta información dicha instancia se añadirá a la lista de Personas.

Perdón que sea tan larga la pregunta pero necesito solucionar este problema para poder realizar los últimos métodos que me quedan. Y ya he buscado por todo y no he encontrado ninguna solución.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Adjunto el git del proyecto entero: https://github.com/MLS535/practicabiblioteca

Comment: No queda claro que debe hacer el método **solicitarDatosPersona** : crear una nueva instancia (de Bibliotecario o Usuario ) o buscar un objeto específico. ( según los criterios indicados al principio de la pregunta ) .

Comment: Hola! solicitarDatosPersona crea un nuevo usuario y un nuevo bibliotecario tal y como lo he hecho. El problema está que SolicitarDatosPersona en la clase Persona es null y que cuando recorro en el metodo accesoPassword, no recoge la información de Bibliotecario y no me busca la contraseña que he puesto.

Comment: Se puede declarar abstracto el método:  **public abstract Persona solicitarDatosPersona();**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si hay una lista de tipo Persona que contiene *Bibliotecarios* y *Usuarios*, y hay que recorrerla buscando un campo que solo existe en Bibliotecario se puede:

- evaluar el tipo con instanceof
- hacer un downcasting sobre el elemento para acceder al método/campo.

ejemplo:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < lista.size() ; i++) {
    Persona temp = lista.get(i);
    if( temp instanceof Bibliotecario) {
        if( ((Bibliotecario) temp).getPassword().equals("pass")) {
            // lo que quieras hacer
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

**temp instanceof Bibliotecario** : evalúa si es instancia de Bibliotecario.

**((Bibliotecario) temp).getPassword().equals("pass")** : evalúa si es la contraseña buscada.

**lista**: es la lista de tipo Persona con instancias de Usuario y Bibliotecario.